# Windows 2016 incremental backup to network share

Tags: network-share, windows-server-2016, incremental-backup, wbadmin

I`m new to Windows 2016 Server. Is there a way to make an incremental backup to network share using native backup software?
I found only one way to do this - create a virtual hard drive file. Is this a good idea? I'm afraid that the file will break

Answer (score 2):

You can backup to network shares and the backups are performed incrementally. What is **not supported** are multiple versions maintained on the network share. You can only access the latest backup version.

Backing up to a local disk is dangerous, because you may loose the original data and the backup in case of hardware faults.

Its better to choose an iSCSI target as backup destination. This can be hosted on a NAS or another Windows server. On those wbadmin supports a backup history with multiple versions.

Since backups are the lifeline when everything else has failed, I would in a business evironement always prefer a professional backup solution. 
Finally these data should be periodically copied to a safe target which isn't permanently connected to the source system. (offsite backup)

Edit:
Article about automated backup on USB drives using wbadmin: [System Image Backups with WbAdmin](https://blog.ligos.net/2016-01-24/System-Image-Backups-With-Wbadmin.html)

Since backups are the lifeline when everything else has failed I would in a business environment always prefer a professional backup solution.

Comment: `You can backup to network shares and the backups are performed incrementally.` I don't think this is true, because in my environment image based backup of Windows Server 2008 R2 is deleting and recreating VHD files always, leading to new names AND Inodes. This makes incremental backups impossible. https://serverfault.com/a/990394/333397